# Install software on bash on ubuntu on windows then add them to PATH

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bash

I'm used to using Linux in my development (I have a Linux PC for work). However, for some reason I had to retain Windows on my personal laptop. I installed Bash on Ubuntu on Windows just so I can still "use" Linux even when working on my personal laptop.

Is there any way I can install my tools in the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (like git, npm, or php for example) and then PATH them into Windows PATH?

Thanks!

Comment: "Is there any way I can install my tools in the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (like git, npm, or php for example) and then PATH them into Windows PATH?" - Not possible at this time.

Comment: oh. so are there any work arounds or so? and you can answer it if  you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work-round, which is to create a batch file for each Linux command. In the examples below, I make a subdirectory `Linux` under the user's home directory to store the batch files. I have also assumed that the commands are typed, rather than executed from a batch file.

First create the subdirectory and add it to `PATH`:-

```
md %HomePath%\Linux
PATH=%PATH%;%HomePath%\Linux
```

- You can add the `Linux` path before the other `PATH` entries if you want the Linux utilities to take precedence over similarly-named Windows applications.
- You can make the change permanent by adding it to the Windows preset paths or by [creating a CMD initialisation file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/5164855).

Now move to the Ubuntu `/bin` directory in order to create the batch files:-

```
cd %LocalAppData%\lxss\rootfs\bin
for %f in (*) do echo @%SystemRoot%\System32\bash.exe -c "%f %*">%HomePath%\Linux\%f.cmd
```

- Linux commands generally do not have embedded blanks, and I have assumed this.
- If you want to include other Linux directories (eg `/usr/bin`, `$HOME/bin`, etc), then run the `for` command in each directory in turn *in reverse order* from how the directories appear in `$PATH`, unless you want to create separate Windows batch directories for each Linux directory.

If you load a Windows X-server you can include Ubuntu GUI applications.